# What is the correct way to alter ComboBox between two DataSources?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking to alter one combobox between two DataSources depending on the button clicked.

Here are the 2 lists:

```
List<ComplaintModel> productNames = new List<ComplaintModel>();
List<ComplaintModel> specificProductNames = new List<ComplaintModel>();
```

This is the functions for both of the Data Sources:

```
public Complaints_Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // When Form is loaded - load with this Data Source First
    loadProducts();

}

private void loadProducts()
{
    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
    productNames = db.LoadProducts();

    product.DataSource = productNames;
    product.DisplayMember = "Product";
    product.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

// On button click - alter the Data Source
public void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // New datasource
    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
    specificProductNames = db.FindOrderNumber(orderNumber.Text);

    product.DataSource = specificProductNames;
    product.DisplayMember = "Product";
    product.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

**Question**

- Is this the correct way of altering between data-sources?

The reason I have this question - the form is actually fairly slow. Especially when I load or clear the textboxes and also clear the data-bindings.